# CGContextDrawImage camera app crash

Tags: ios, memory, crash, avcapturesession

I am trying to obtain an image using the AVCaptureSession. I followed this tutorial http://www.benjaminloulier.com/posts/2-ios4-and-direct-access-to-the-camera. I am creating uiimage from image ref and then obtaining pixels from that uiimage.
But the app crashes after sometime (less than 30s). I tried analyzing using Leaks and that too crashes. Using logs I found the app crashes just before the line  CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, image1.CGImage);
Do you guys have any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong. I also see Memory Allocation errors a few seconds before the app crashes. Please help.

The code is posted below..

```
// Create a UIImage from sample buffer data

- (UIImage *) imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer 
{
lock = @"YES";

 CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer); 

// Lock the base address of the pixel buffer
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0); 

// Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer); 

// Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer); 
// Get the pixel buffer width and height
size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer); 
size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer); 

// Create a device-dependent RGB color space
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); 


size_t bufferSize = CVPixelBufferGetDataSize(imageBuffer);

// Create a Quartz direct-access data provider that uses data we supply.
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:baseAddress length:bufferSize];

CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);

CGImageRef quartzImage = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, bytesPerRow,
              colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little,
              dataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);

// Unlock the pixel buffer

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

// Create an image object from the Quartz image
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage];

// Release the Quartz image
CGImageRelease(quartzImage);

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
baseAddress = nil;
[data  release];
lock = @"NO";
return(image);
}

-(void)calculate
{
@try {

        UIImage *image1 = [self stillImage];   //Capture an image from the camera.
        //Extract the pixels from the camera image.

        CGColorSpaceRef colourSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

        size_t bytesPerRow = image1.size.width*4;
        unsigned char* bitmapData = (unsigned char*)malloc(bytesPerRow*image1.size.height);

        CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(bitmapData, image1.size.width, image1.size.height, 8, bytesPerRow,colourSpace,kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst|kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

        CGColorSpaceRelease(colourSpace);

        CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, image1.CGImage);

        unsigned char* pixels = (unsigned char*)CGBitmapContextGetData(context);

        totalLuminance = 0.0;
        for(int p=0; p<image1.size.width*image1.size.height*4; p+=4)
        {
            totalLuminance += pixels[p]*0.3 + pixels[p+1]*0.59 + pixels[p+2]*0.11;
        }

        totalLuminance /= (image1.size.height * image1.size.width);                   

        pixels = nil;

        bitmapData = nil;

        [image1 release];

    CGContextRelease(context);
        //image1 = nil;

        //totalLuminance = [n floatValue];                   //Calculate the total luminance.
        float f = [del.camcont.slider value];
        float total = totalLuminance * f;
        NSString *ns = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lux : %0.2f", total];
        NSLog(@"slider = %f",f);
        NSLog(@"totlaluminance = %f",totalLuminance);
        NSLog(@"%@",ns);
        //NSString *ns = [NSString initWithFormat:@"Lux : %0.2f", total];
        [del.camcont.lux setText:ns];//Display the total luminance.

        self.stillImage = nil;
        //[self.stillImage release];
         ns = nil;
        //n = nil;
        //del = nil;
    }

    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"main: Caught %@: %@", [exception name], [exception reason]);
}
}
```

Comment: You might want to provide the symbolicated crash log so we can see details of the crash? See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Comment: @viks , had you found any solution for this?,I'm facing same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear as to why you're taking the `CMSampleBufferRef` and then creating a `CGImageRef` and then a `UIImage` and then taking that `UIImage`'s `CGImageRef` and sucking out the data and then pushing that into an `unsigned char` pointer (which points to, essentially, the same bytes that were in the `CMSampleBufferRef` in the first place).

You will simplify your life (and you should find it easier to debug) if you do something like this:

```
CVPixelBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer); 
size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer); 
size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer); 
uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
uint8_t *pixels = malloc(bytesPerRow*height);
memcpy(pixels, baseAddress, bytesPerRow*height);
baseAddress = nil;
imageBuffer = nil;
sampleBuffer = nil;
float totalLuminance = 0.0;
for(int r=0; r<height; r++)
{
   for(int p=0, p<width, p+=4)
   {
      totalLuminance += pixels[p+(r*bytesPerRow)]*0.3 
                     + pixels[p+1+(r*bytesPerRow)]*0.59 
                     + pixels[p+2+(r*bytesPerRow)]*0.11;
   {
}
free(pixels);
totalLuminance /= (width * height);
```

(The nested `for` loops are to compensate for the fact that `bytesPerRow` cannot be assumed to be the same as `width*4`, due to padding.)

Comment: Thank you for your response.Its true.I haven't noticed the complexity I have made unnecessarily.Thank you again.That will definitely help my app's performance.By the way,I cant upvote your answer since I dont have enough reputation.Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Memory management looks ok at first glance. As a workaround, you can consider UIImage [-imageWithData:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithData%3a)
 in case there's something off about the custom CGImageCreate code. This because you're using the CGImage to create a UIImage anyway.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But it is not working using imageWithData. Keeps failing at the same line after a few seconds.

Comment: It was worth a try.  Are you able to post the crash log?  If you submitted this incident to Apple DTS for example, that's the first thing they'll ask for...

Comment: But there is no crash log found in Xcode organizer.I added NSLog after each line and found that each time the app just closes at some point without any crash log or any error message in the console.